# Cannot set a breakpoint on Angular application

Tags: angular, debugging, firefox, breakpoints, firefox-quantum

On Firefox Quantum (57.0 64-bit), when I try to set a breakpoint on an Angular application using the Debugger pane, the breakpoint immediately disappear and it is not actually set.

See a video of the behavior here: 
https://youtu.be/aBQ0wOeIYYQ

For the video I created a new angular project with angular-cli:

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.4.0
OS: darwin x64
```

Then I serve the project using `ng serve`.

I tried on Chrome and the breakpoint is correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a deugger statement in your code.  Just open the developer tools and it should stop on that line when it hits it.